# Java ArrayList implementation of geneirics

Tags: java, generics

I was going through java source code for ArrayList i came across below code

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private E[] newElementArray(int size) {
        return (E[]) new Object[size];
    }
```

Here we trying to cast object[] to any E which we use when we declare Array List.

So i wrote code to test this as below :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

class A {

}

class CheckBox extends A {

}

public class Box<T> {

    public  T t;

    public void set(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<Integer> box = new Box<Integer>();
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();



        box.newElementArray(10);

        Box[] a = (Box[]) new Object[10];

    }

    // prefer wild card as it does not allow to corrupt your data types
    public void wildCard(Set<?> test) {
        test.add(null);
    }

    private T[] newElementArray(int size) {
        System.out.println(" casting object  to t");
        return (T[]) new Object[size];
    }

}
```

Surprisingly  line **box.newElementArray(10);** works fine but

```
        Box[] a = (Box[]) new Object[10];
```

does not work , though both do same thing. Can anybody let me know what could be reason behind it or my  understanding is wrong?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong.  Due to generic erasure, the `(E[])` cast doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of type erasure, Java compiler replaces E with Object. So the method newElementArray(int size) becomes

```
private Object[] newElementArray(int size) {
    return (Object[]) new Object[size];
}
```

which makes its invocation successful.

You can refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html for the details.

Comment: BUt finally Object[] is casted to E[] after the method call which is nothing but cast to integer or any other types how does it work

Comment: No, it is not casted to Integer. It is casted to Object[]. In your code, it is casted to E[]. When you compiled this code, Java compiler modifies E[] to Object[]. The fact that you create the variable "box" with type Box<Integer> does not have any impact on how Java compiler replaces E[].